# Looking for reference on triangulating convex (or regular) $n$-gons

Tags: geometry, reference-request

Looking for reference on triangulating convex (or regular) $n$-gons.

There are some basic interesting facts on them, like the number of triangulations of an $n$-gon is the $n-2$ Catalan number. I'm looking for a more in depth exposition, and google is failing me.

Thanks!

P.S. I have access to Springer's electronic database of books through my university

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mansour, Rastegar *On typical triangulations of a convex n-gon*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.04025.pdf).  Lots of additional references as well.

From the abstract:

> ... among other things, we give new proofs for already known results
> such as the degree of a fixed vertex and the number of ears in [a
> random triangulation] $T_n$, as well as, provide new results on the
> number of “blue” angles and refined information on the distribution of
> angles at a fixed vertex ...

See also [Mašović et al, *Orbiting Triangle Method For Convex Polygon Triangulation*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/26511386)

Answer (score 0):

See Chapter 1 of the wonderful book [Discrete and Computational Geometry](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9489.html) by Devadoss and O'Rourke. That chapter is freely available.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to print this first chapter?